# how to remove wrong commit from pull request made on github

Tags: github

I have opened pull request say no 865 with branch name say PACS-36, and than we commit to PACS-36, now we see one wrong commit, and want to remove that, but not able to do it,

i have removed the commit from branch, forced pushed, restore branch, and many other tries, but still the commit there,

Can not reopen the pull request too, but I want to remove that particular commit

Answer (score 0):

If you force-push a branch which is the source of a Pull Request on GitHub, that PR will be updated with the new branch history.

That means you can do locally:

- an interactive rebase (to drop the wrong commit)
- a `git push --force`